# case when oracle BI

Tags: oracle, case-when

I have created a basic case when statement that assess a list of staff IDs and determines whether they are 'training' or 'paid'.

However, there are some staff who should have both categories against their ID but it will only show as 'training' - because this is where they first appear in the statement.

Is it possible to correct this?

```
case 
   when People."Record Key" IN ( list of IDs) then 'training' 
   when People."Record Key" IN ( list of IDs ) then 'paid' 
END
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone has both?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two rows for employees Paid and in Training, you can do in this way:

```
SELECT People.Name, 'Training' category
  FROM People
 WHERE People."Record Key" IN ( list of IDs )
 UNION
SELECT People.Name, 'Paid'
  FROM People
 WHERE People."Record Key" IN (other list of IDs )
```